# Can a Gloom Stalker Ranger choose to be seen in darkness?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, vision-and-light

In XGE, the Gloom Stalker level 3 feature "Umbral Sight" states that a Gloom Stalker is invisible to any creature that relies on darkvision to see you in the darkness. (p. 42, XGE)

That sounds like a permanent effect, but I was wondering if there had been any official word on whether or not this effect could be more or less turned off or on at will.

Comment: you should use more tags... without a D&D5 tag is hard to "guess" what XGE means (Xanathar's Guide to Everything)...

Comment: I was only able to use 1 tag due to being new here. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I tweeted this question](https://twitter.com/CascadeOW/status/961014694646513664) at Mike Mearls:

> Quick question: Can a Gloom Stalker choose to be seen by creatures relying on darkvision in darkness, or is it a permanent effect? Thanks!

And [he responded](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/961024229633277953):

> I believe you can always choose to make yourself visible to a creature.

In other words, yes, you can more or less "turn on/off" the Umbral Sight feature at will.

Comment: It's worth noting that Mearls' rulings are not official, and have often been wrong. Only Jeremy Crawford's rulings are considered official, as he's the rules designer for 5e.

Answer (score 8):

The key here is the description of Umbral Sight in Xanathar's Guide.

> **You are also adept at evading creatures that rely
>   on darkvision**. While in darkness, you are invisible
>   to any creature that relies on darkvision to see you in
>   that darkness.

To me, this implies that for the invisibility to occur, the ranger must be actively evading the creature relying on darkvision.

I looked over at Jeremy Crawford's twitter to see if he answered a similar question. Someone posed the same question as you in late 2017, but unfortunately did not receive a response.

Comment: It's worth noting that many of Crawford's answer with respect to class features are all along the same line: You choose whether or not to use them. For instance, I can elect to move how I please in favoured terrain as a Ranger. I don't HAVE to move at a fast pace just because we've been travelling for an hour.

Answer (score -1):

Officially, no, not that I have heard. I have always considered attributes like that to not be under the player's control.  It adds a dimension of risk and strategy when you think a buff like that can only be positive but there could actually be a downside that the enemy can outsmart.

However, that being said, you can modify the scenario so that the creature is no longer relying on darkvision, which will bypass that power.