# How powerful is the invisibility granted by the Gloom Stalker ranger's Umbral Sight feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, vision-and-light, invisibility

The [Gloom Stalker ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GloomStalker)'s Umbral Sight feature, which is granted when a ranger chooses the Gloom Stalker archetype at level 3, states:

> You are also adept at evading creatures that rely on darkvision. While
>   in darkness, you are invisible to any creature that relies on
>   darkvision to see you in that darkness.

Source: *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 42

I read this as saying that as long as the ranger remains in darkness, the ranger remains indefinitely invisible to all creatures that would otherwise be able to see the ranger with darkvision. Even attacking or casting a spell, which normally causes an invisibility effect to end early, would not cause it to end in this situation. A Gloom Stalker ranger could attack repeatedly from melee range, without ever moving to a different spot, and still remain unseen. Only a creature with a special sense such as truesight or blindsight would be able to see the ranger, as long as the ranger remains in darkness.

Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Related: [Can a Gloom Stalker Ranger choose to be seen in darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114967/can-a-gloom-stalker-ranger-choose-to-be-seen-in-darkness)

Comment: note: a Warlock with Devil's Sight would also be able to see you, since he doesn't have darkvision, but rather "can see normally in darkness".

Comment: Note that anyone with a light source can make you visible to everyone. The humble Light cantrip reveals all Gloom Stalkers in a 40ft radius for 1 hour. A Bullseye Lantern casts a 120ft cone for up to 6 hours.

Comment: Dancing Lights may only have a 10ft radius, but four of them moving 60ft as a bonus action can chase the Gloom Stalker around the battlefield, potentially making a fun encounter all on its own. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Your interpretation is correct.

As the feature description states, you are invisible while in darkness to any creature that is only able to see you thanks to its darkvision. It doesn't have the restrictions of the *invisibility* spell, only its own (previously stated) restriction. And as you note, you can attack from within 5 feet of an enemy without disadvantage, since the ["Ranged Attacks in Close Combat"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#RangedAttacksinCloseCombat) specifies that the enemy must be able to see you (and not be incapacitated) in order for it to cause you to have disadvantage when attacking from within 5 feet of it.

Certain other special senses may allow the creature to see you without relying on darkvision, as you have noted.

(Note that being invisible doesn't automatically make you hidden, so creatures in combat still know where you are unless the DM determines otherwise or you take the Hide action. It does, however, allow you to take the Hide action anywhere that you're invisible to enemies looking for you, i.e when you're in darkness and the enemy would require darkvision to see you.)

Comment: you should add that you still give away your location when you attack

Comment: @Vylix: Since you're not hidden unless you take the Hide action (which being invisible does let you do anywhere that you're invisible to those looking for you), your location is "given away" even before attacking.